# Refer to key-value in ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a key-value pair defined in the Web.Release.config and Web.Debug.config for a url.
In the C# file I use it like so (key is "Report-URL"):

```
string reportUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Report-URL"];
CoverSheetReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportUrl);
```

This works but now I want to use it in a .ascx file where I currently have the url hardcoded:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkReports" runat="server" CssClass="LeftNav" 
NavigateUrl="http://mygroup-dev-appsr/ReportServer?%2fASD%2fTransactions%2fCoverSheet&rs:Command=ListChildren" />
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with help of **[Inline Syntax](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112)**

```
NavigateUrl="<%$ AppSettings:Report-URL %>
```

**or**

In .ascx

```
<a href="<%# this.GetReportUrl() %>">Report</a>
```

in .ascx.cs

```
protected string GetReportUrl(){
 string reportUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                   .AppSettings["Report-URL"]; 

 return  new Uri(reportUrl).ToString();
}
```

**[Another Syntax Reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx)**

Comment: I'm getting a HTTP 400 Error, but mine is a little different in than your example because I don't have href. '<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkReports" runat="server" CssClass="LeftNav" NavigateUrl="<%=this.GetReportUrl() %>"

Comment: @mickey, What is the url you see when you hover on a link? is it a valid url generated for your site?

Comment: May it is not calling the method. The url shown in the brower (upon the 400 error is): http://localhost:39536/Admin/Components/%3C%25=this.GetReportUrl()%20%25%3E

Comment: @mickey, Try replacing `=` with '#` and see

Comment: Tried that, now the link doesn't work at all.  NavigateUrl="<%#this.GetReportUrl() %>"

Comment: @mickey, have you checked the url now? same or different?

Comment: There is no url in the 2nd case because the link doesn't work at all, ie clicking on the link does nothing.

Comment: NavigateUrl="<%$ AppSettings:Report-URL %>